# Android Studio is not launching on my laptop

Tags: android

After I installed Android Studio and tried opening, it didn't launch. Please provide some help , thank you. [Here is a picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwlvD.jpg)

Comment: Have you also installed the SDK for andriod?

Comment: Please explain your problem instead of providing an imgur link.

Comment: image explain nothing. add steps you have followed

Answer (score 0):

Some times it is the most easy step:

Just Remove everything and Reinstall Android Studio again.